# Codec Negotiates but no Audio :G729

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, sip, codec

I have built the library file of g729 codec, the library is built successfully and codec negotiates perfectly but there is no audio on either side.

I am using the reference of an open source project [Sipdroid](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/)

Here is my resource files:
[G729.java](http://pastie.org/4840321)
[Android.mk](http://pastie.org/4840308)
[g729_jni.cpp](http://pastie.org/4837653)

Comment: What does the offer/answer exchange look like? Have you run a wireshark on one of the clients (or somewhere between them) to see if traffic's actually leaving either client, and where it's going?

Comment: No i didn't used wireshark and yeah can post my SDP logs for same